# Use different calender and format info for DateTime.ToString() and DateTime.Parse() in Asp.Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, globalization, persian-calendar

I use globalization and localization in my Asp.Net Core app and i want to use PersianCalendar when requested culture is set to 'fa-IR'.

This needs to happen whenever a `DateTime.ToString()` happens. I want it to be converted to persian date automatically and i don't want to change the code that is calling ToString() method (because other cultures still needs to see gregorian calendar).

The request localization works fine and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is correclty set to 'fa-IR' but the default calendar for 'fa-IR' culture is `GregorianCalendar`.

So i created a subclass of `CultureInfo` like this:

```
public class PersianCulture : CultureInfo
{
    private readonly Calendar _calendar;
    private readonly Calendar[] _optionalCalendars;
    private DateTimeFormatInfo _dateTimeFormatInfo;

    public PersianCulture() : base("fa-IR") {
        _calendar = new PersianCalendar();

        _optionalCalendars = new List<Calendar>
        {
            new PersianCalendar(),
            new GregorianCalendar()
        }.ToArray();

        var dateTimeFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR").DateTimeFormat;
        dateTimeFormatInfo.Calendar = _calendar;
        _dateTimeFormatInfo = dateTimeFormatInfo;
    }

    public override Calendar Calendar => _calendar;

    public override Calendar[] OptionalCalendars => _optionalCalendars;

    public override DateTimeFormatInfo DateTimeFormat {
        get => _dateTimeFormatInfo;
        set => _dateTimeFormatInfo = value;
    }
}
```

Then i added a middleware that checks if requested culture is 'fa-IR' then sets the `CurrentCulture` to `PersianCulture` as follows:

```
if ( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fa-IR" ) {
        var culture = new PersianCulture();
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
   }
```

And i get the expected result. Whenever a `someDate.ToString()` is called the output is converted to persian date. For exapmle `DateTime.Now.ToString()` will output `16/10/1400 02:53:40 ب.ظ`.

The problem is the same `Calendar` and `DateTimeFormatInfo` is used whenever a `DateTime.Parse()` happens and the parsed date will be wrong because the source is in gregorian format but treated as persian.

How can i use my custom `PersianCulture` class for converting to string and use C# default's 'fa-IR' calendar for parsing dates?

Comment: What do you mean by "requested culture" exactly? `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` _still_ checks the machine culture that your code works. It's _not_ the client culture or something.

Comment: @SonerGönül Requested culture is the culture that user selected to use and you capture it using "app.UseRequestLocalization" middleware. What it does it sets `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` based on user preference.

Comment: @SonerGönül Note that request localization is not the problem here. You could assume that i'm trying to reach my goal by setting `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` by hand. Now the question is How can i use my custom `PersianCulture` class for converting to string and use C# default's 'fa-IR' calendar for parsing dates?